# Why does the StreamWriter fail to write strings of a length less than or equal to 3 to .csv files?

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

`_flagImageSources` is a string array of 195 file paths to `.png` files of flags.
Each file path is of the format `C:\Users\user\someFolder\...\Flags\xx.png`, where `xx` is a country-code top level domain (e.g. `.uk` for the United Kingdom).

When executing the code in "Code Snippet 1" the output to the initially empty `output.csv` file is as shown in "CSV File Output 1":

**Code Snippet 1**

```
_streamWriter = new StreamWriter("output.csv");

string str;
string outputText;
for (int i = 0; i < _flagImageSources.Length; i++)
{
  str = _flagImageSources[i];
  outputText = str.Substring(68, 6);
  _streamWriter.WriteLine(outputText);
}
```

**CSV File Output 1**

```
ae.png
af.png
⋮
zw.png
```

However, the moment I reduce the sub-string length from 6 to 3 (or less), I get the output the out put is an empty `.csv` file.

**Code Snippet 2**

```
_streamWriter = new StreamWriter("output.csv");

string str;
string outputText;
for (int i = 0; i < _flagImageSources.Length; i++)
{
  str = _flagImageSources[i];
  outputText = str.Substring(68, 3);
  _streamWriter.WriteLine(outputText);
}
```

**CSV File Output 2:** "an empty file"

I do not understand why I cannot write strings of a length of 3 (or less) to my `.csv` file. Does anyone understand why this is and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not flushing the output or properly closing and then disposing the stream.  You need to either set `AutoFlush` to `true` or manually call `.Flush()` and then `.Close()` and ultimately `.Dispose()`.

```
_streamWriter = new StreamWriter("output.csv");

string str;
string outputText;
for (int i = 0; i < _flagImageSources.Length; i++)
{
  str = _flagImageSources[i];
  outputText = str.Substring(68, 3);
  _streamWriter.WriteLine(outputText);
}

_streamWriter.Flush(); 
_streamWriter.Close();
// prev. two lines are redundant b/c dispose will accomplish this.
_streamWriter.Dispose();
```

All this will happen automatically if you use the `Disposable` pattern, which is the preferred approach:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _flagImageSources.Length; i++)
    {
      string str = _flagImageSources[i];
      string outputText = str.Substring(68, 3);
      sw.WriteLine(outputText);
    }   
}
```

Comment: While you're refactoring, there is absolutely noting positive to say about declaring those two strings outside the loop.

Comment: @bommelding Nor declaring them in the first place, that could all be inlined to the `WriteLine` call

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- I find inlining isn't always great because it makes debugging trickier; it's good to  be able to look at the values of variables assigned above.  That's only if it doesn't cause the methods to be too many lines, though.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: A matter of taste - I don't mind doing things in a few independent steps. Also helps debugging, refactoring and sometimes readability.

Comment: @rory.ap Adding `_streamWriter.Dispoe()`to my code solved the problem, but do you know why the StreamWriter is successful in writing to the file when the sub-string length is greater than 3?

Comment: It's all part of the magic of streaming.  It writes it out in segments in a seemingly-unpredictable way (I'm sure there's a logic to it, but I don't really care).  Just implement the disposable pattern and don't think about it.

Comment: @K.Claesson I agree with rory that you shouldn't care, but more specifically the writer is going to buffer the data and do one big write when the buffer is full.  The first example hits that buffer length and the second which is less data doesn't.